# If $N$ is the cyclic subgroup generated by $x$, then $N$ is normal in $G$ iff $g$ belongs to $G$ implies $gxg^{-1}=x^k$ where $k$ is an integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My attempt : $N$ is the cyclic subgroup of $G$ generated by $x$. If $g\in G$ then $(gxg^{-1})^r=gx^r g^{-1}= (x^k)^r =(x^r)^k$. Since $(x^r)^k\in N$ this implies that $(gxg^{-1})^r\in N$. Hence $N$ is a normal subgroup.

If $N$ is a normal subgroup then $gx^rg^{-1}\in N$ which implies that $gx^rg^{-1}=(x^r)^m$ thus  $gxg^{-1}=x^{mr-r-1} =x^k$.

Comment: Format your question using $mathjax$ take a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: In addition to formatting your question properly, please make it clear what exactly you're asking.  Are you having trouble with something, or are you asking us to check whether your solution is correct?

Comment: Please take the trouble to format properly. Math needs to be enclosed by \$. Exponents of more than one character need to be inside $\{\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof has the right idea, but I have some comments on how you've presented it.

> If $g \in G$.....

Here, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to prove. When reading it, I assumed you were trying to prove the forward direction (Because it starts "$g$ belongs to $G$..."), but you were actually proving the backwards direction. Make it clear what you are doing,  so that your reader (grader) understands what you wrote. What is $k$? What is $r$? **Write it down**

As for the actual proof: for the forward direction, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. It's easier to directly use the definition of normality: Because $x \in N$, $g \in G$, we know that $gxg^{-1} \in N$. Because $N$ is cyclic, we know $gxg^{-1} = x^k$ for some $k$.

For the backwards direction, let $g \in G$, and $n \in N$. We will show that $gng^{-1} \in N$. Because $N$ is cyclic, we can write $n = x^m$ for some $m$. Then, $$gng^{-1} = gx^mg^{-1} = (gxg^{-1})^m = (x^k)^m  = x^{km} \in N$$.

Comment: I'll be careful about my presentation from now on.  Thank you...